# Adding Vector File Server Layer In QGIS w Plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, vector-tiles

I'm using QGIS 3.8 and trying to connect to the following vector tile server layer using the latest version of the vector tile reader plugin: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e370f9e3a3b941d68f37632b6e16e601#overview.

On the website, the layer links to https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/pWwHCwVEtR8QoS9x/arcgis/rest/services/Uniti_Leasing_Fiber/VectorTileServer and the View Styles button links to https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/pWwHCwVEtR8QoS9x/arcgis/rest/services/Uniti_Leasing_Fiber/VectorTileServer/resources/styles/root.json?f=pjson.

No matter how I configure the input in the "Edit Connection" in QGIS, I get the error "The field Vector Layer' is required but not found.  This is an invalid Tile JSON."

How should the edit connection fields be filled out to avoid this error and pull in the data?